# How to set print preview of existing template in a form?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, report

Am displaying 3 reports in lookup edit (drop down) now how if he select any one report I need to display the preview in that same form how to show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Use PrintControl to show your report in the form as i am doing..:

```
PrintControl control = new PrintControl();
SomeForm.Controls.Add(control);

/// Put this code to show report in Printcontrol at SomeForm
public void SetReport(XtraReport report)
{
            if (report != null)
            {
                control.PrintingSystem = report.PrintingSystem;
                SetupButtonVisability();
                report.CreateDocument();
                report.RecreateDocumentMap();                
                control.PrintingSystem = report.PrintingSystem;              
            }
}
```

Another way you can populate print view using the below documentation link too:
[How to: Invoke a Report's Print Preview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2573)

```
   XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();

    using (ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(report)) {
        // Invoke the Print Preview form modally, 
        // and load the report document into it.
        printTool.ShowPreviewDialog();

        // Invoke the Print Preview form
        // with the specified look and feel setting.
        printTool.ShowPreview(UserLookAndFeel.Default);
    }
```

Comment: How to remove or hide main menu and tool bar from that preview ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use documentviewer control of devexpress for same.

Pass selected report object to document viewer.

Follow below tutorial

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument2668